# How to increase battery capacity in ubuntu?

Tags: battery

[Battery capacity is way lower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEPZQ.png)

*Windows provided more battery capacity as I need to charge my laptop (when on ubuntu) in every 1 and a half hour.*

Comment: Capacity is controlled by the battery rather than the OS. They generally degrade over time and there is little people can do to prevent it. You may be able to eke out more operational time by tweaking the power settings, enforcing CPU caps when not connected to power, and turning off WiFi/Bluetooth when they’re not required 

Answer (score 3):

I am using two tools that helped me a) to figure out what sucks the energy and b)reduces the power consumption:

a) Powertop finds the resource hogs and displays a solution how to disable them permanently.

b) TLP (which I used on my Thinkpads, but works with other laptops as well) is controlling the power consumption. You need to edit the `/etc/tlp.conf' for your needs. Linrunner has an excellent [webpage](https://linrunner.de/tlp/introduction.html) where the configuration is explained in detail